Quotient of Special Linear Group by its centre
I am currently writing my Master's Thesis about Moduli Spaces of Groups Representations via the GIT quotient, i.e. in the context of Algebraic Geometry. Hence, algebraic groups are fundamental objects of study. For the general theory of algebraic groups, I have mainly studied the book by Humphreys. However, via a MathStack post, I saw that a fundamental result on quotients of linear algebraic groups was in the book of Springer, so I took a look of it. It is the following:
Proposition 5.5.10 Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and $H$ a closed, normal subgroup.
(i) $G/H$ is an affine variety.
(ii) Provided with the usual group structure, $G/H$ is a linear algebraic group.
Let us focus on the particular case $G=\mathsf{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$. Its centre is the group
$$ Z:=Z(\mathsf{SL}(n,\mathbb{C}))=\{ \lambda I_n:\lambda^n=1 \}, $$
where $I_n$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Since $Z$ is isomorphic to the group of $n$-th roots of unity, $Z$ is a finite subgroup, so it looks that it is a closed subgroup. Hence, the above proposition should implies that $\mathsf{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})/Z\cong \mathsf{PSL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a linear algebraic group. However, I have read some MathStack posts (see $\operatorname{PSL}_n$ as an algebraic group) which talk about how this group is NOT an algebraic group and not a variety at all. Am I misunderstanding something? Thank you in advance!

This is one of those cases where being careful about technicalities is obscuring the actual content. $\mathrm{PSL}_n$ is a linear algebraic group. Full stop. If you are working over $\mathbb{C}$, which it appears you are, just stop reading here. If not, then the subtlety is just that $\mathrm{PSL}_n(K)\ne \mathrm{SL}_n(K)/Z(K)$ when $K$ is not algebraically closed. This is a technical point that I can explain more if you’d like, but if you’re working over $\mathbb{C}$ I think you’re fine to ignore it.

It may be more helpful to think of $\mathrm{SL}_n / Z$ as $\mathrm{PGL}_n$.

@AlexYoucis I work generally with an algebraically closed field $K$ and particularly with $\mathbb{C}$, so I guess that's enough! Thank you

@JoshuaMundinger Since I work with algebraically closed fields, this isomorphism also solves the problem. Thank you!
